# Default operator AND using SOLR on Coldfusion

Tags: solr, coldfusion

I just want the default operator to be AND and not an OR for every basic search. For a particular collection, in the schema.xml and solrconfig.xml files I set the defaultOperator to AND (makes no difference) and set the mm to 100%, restart the CF Add-on Server services and still no difference when doing a search. I am on Coldfusion 2018.

```
<cfsearch

name='qHearings'

collection='hearings_collection'

criteria='conflicts of interest'

/>
```

returns me documents with words 'conflicts' OR 'interest'. If I change it to:

```
<cfsearch

name='qHearings'

collection='hearings_collection'

criteria='conflicts AND of AND interest'

/>
```

returns me documents with words 'conflicts' AND 'interest'. This is good but my users don't like be told to use AND and I hear endless comments about why can't it be like google search :(

I have been reading up on SOLR and it seems like many have the same problem but I try the suggestions but  I always get an OR search result.

Anyone got basic SOLR search to default to AND?

Comment: What query parser does the `cfsearch` plugin use by default? Can you see the actual query sent to the Solr server in the Solr log? You can configure static and default parameters for a given result handler (such as `/search`) in `solrconfig.xml`, which allows you to set `q.op=AND` as the default value.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @MatsLindh, your comments lead me to the right path! I was setting

`<solrQueryParser q.op="AND"/>`

in the schema.xml thinking that was where I was suppose to do it (of course, it made no difference I still got an OR search result).

I couldn't find a Solr log for Coldfusion but I played around with solrconfig.xml file for one particular collection. After re-reading your comments I added

```
<str name="q.op">AND</str>
```

to the "standard" handler and it worked! I am somewhat embarrassed because it wasn't obvious to me to do it that way and for all my googling I didn't see examples of it being done that way (I only saw it as being passed in a query parameter).

So my standard handler looks like this:

```
<requestHandler name="standard" class="solr.StandardRequestHandler" default="true">
<!-- default values for query parameters -->
<lst name="defaults">
<str name="echoParams">explicit</str>
<str name="hl.fl">summary title </str>
<str name="df">contents</str>
<str name="q.op">AND</str>
<str name="mm">100%</str>
<!-- omp = Only More Popular -->
<str name="spellcheck.onlyMorePopular">false</str>
<!-- exr = Extended Results -->
<str name="spellcheck.extendedResults">false</str>
<!-- The number of suggestions to return -->
<str name="spellcheck.count">1</str>
</lst>
<arr name="last-components">
<str>spellcheck</str>
</arr>
</requestHandler>
```

Super embarrassing for me that the solution was so simple.

Comment: Don't kick yourself: that was not at all obvious. :-) I, too, have been looking all over for a solution for this. Thanks for sharing it. One added tip: after making this change, folks will need to reload the collection (which can be done in the CF Admin on the Collections page), or by restarting the CF add-on service of course. Note also that cfcollection supports an action="reload", though the docs don't currently indicate that. I've just filed a bug report to that effect, at tracker.adobe.com/#/view/CF-4220801.)

Comment: Here's a bit more, beyond my last comment: while we do need to change the solrconfig.xml for any EXISTING collections (such as in \ColdFusion2023\cfusion\jetty\multicore\collections\yourcollection\conf\solrconfig.xml), note that if you want this to take effect for all FUTURE collections created within CF, you'd need to edit the "template" version of this file. In a typical install, that's found in \ColdFusion2023\cfusion\jetty\multicore\template\conf\solrconfig.xml. No need to restart the CF add on service. It takes effect on next collection created, whether via the CF Admin or cfcollection.